# Singleton class static variable set to nil each time

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, shared

I am making a singleton class for my use . I have seen code for singleton class is like this:

```
//First Example

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
     });
    return sharedMyManager;
 }


 //Second Example

static SingletonSample *sharedObject;

+ (SingletonSample*)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedObject == nil) {
        sharedObject = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedObject;
}
```

The seconds seems fine and understandable. But i am confused in  First example where sharedMyManager is set to nil each time and also there is a allocation of shared manager each time, my doubt is that how will first example return the same reference of the class(Singleton).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all when static is declared with in  function, it is declared only once. So, the line

```
static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
```

Will be executed only once when the function gets called for first time.

In the next line when you use `dispath_once`, it will be executed for only once. So the creation of `sharedMyManager` will be done once only. So, thats a perfect way to create a single ton class.

Answer (score 2):

As it's `static` it will initially be set to `nil`, but in subsequent calls the value will remain to whatever you have set it to in previous calls.

The first example is better as it is thread safe.  The second example doesn't even initialise `sharedObject` which is dangerous (I don't believe there is a guarantee that global variables are initialised to zero).

Comment: There is a guarantee in C for "global" objects and there is a guarantee in Objective-C for references when using ARC, except of references qualified as `__unsafe_unretained`. (This guarantee also applies for "local" objects.)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad OK cheers.  I would always initialise explicitly, however.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad "Correct" is a subjective term.  The first example is better.

Comment: No, "correct" refers to standards and/or documentation. "Better" is a subject term. However I agree that I would use the first example.

Answer (score 1):

`sharedMyManager is set to nil each time`

static variables are set only once.

`there is a allocation of shared manager each time`

You use `dispatch_once`, so it's incorrect too.

Read about dispatch_once [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once).
And using GCD is faster and thread safe.

Comment: It's set "each time"?  No, it's not.